# diagnose unused components in vue project

Tags: vue.js, components

I recently, have joint to a Vue project which is relatively large, and want to find unused components to remove them from the project. Actually, there is a clean-up approach behind the story.

eslint/unused-component config just specifies if a component that is registered locally, is used or not. however, I want to find an unused component and remove its file from the project.
after a while, I found the check-unused-comp package but it doesn't work fine. It recommends some components that are used in different files.

Is there any other way to achieve this goal?

Comment: See https://github.com/BerniWittmann/vue-unused-components-checker

Comment: @rudolfbyker this could be an answer instead of a comment I think.

Comment: With more details and not just a link, yes.

Answer (score 4):

Pen and paper, use your Vue devtools to find out which ones are unused.

Otherwise, you could access each component, and list its own components (via a mixin injected through `mounted`). Doing that recursively from top to bottom, flatting out the final array of all of them, deduping, and getting the final result to diff the ones used and unused.